# Adding dates to feature collection that work with ee.Filter.calendarRange

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I'm using Google Earth Engine in Python, but I'm guessing this problem is not specific to Python. I want to use `ee.Filter.calendarRange` on a feature collection. I was successful at using `ee.Filter.calendarRange` for an image collection from images stored on the server. I think I need to use `ee.ImageCollection.getRegion` to avoid doing computations on entire images. So, I am taking the output from getRegion and creating features from it that I'd like to do the computations on. The problem is that I don't know how to set feature dates in such a way that can be understood by `ee.Filter.calendarRange`. I get `EEException: Collection.filter: Can't apply calendarRange filter to objects without a timestamp.`.

I have an example code that creates 10 dates from Jan 1 to Jan 10, 2010 with "data" values from 0-9. I would like to create a feature collection with just the feature from Jan 3.

```
def make_fts( val ):
    date = start_date.advance( ee.Number( val ), 'day' )
    ft = ee.Feature( None, {'system:time_start': date, 'data': val} )
    return ft

fake_vals = ee.List( [ee.Number( num ) for num in range(10)] )
start_date = ee.Date( '2010-01-01' )
fc = ee.FeatureCollection( fake_vals.map( make_fts ) )
day_ee_num = ee.Number( 3 )
day_filter = ee.Filter.calendarRange( day_ee_num, day_ee_num, 'day_of_month' ) 
day_three_fc = fc.filter( day_filter )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the date as an integer in milliseconds since 1970. You can convert it using `.millis()`.

`ft = ee.Feature( None, {'system:time_start': date.millis(), 'data': val} )`

Comment: Thanks for the idea @JonasV. I'm getting the error as before though. It seems to me that dates are already internally stored as Epoch/Unix. E.g. "date = ee.Date( '2010-01-01' );
print(date.getInfo()) gives {'type': 'Date', 'value': 1262304000000}"

Comment: I tested your minimum example with my change and it works perfectly. Make sure in your original code, that you only save dates to `system:time_start` that have been converted with `millis()`. If my solution doesn't work, there has to be another problem in your original script that is not captured with your minimum example.

Comment: Indeed. I had a typo. Thanks so much. I think this gets me unstuck.